# Statically mapping a PHP script to another script using an .htaccess file results in 404 errors

Tags: php, htaccess, apache, url-rewriting, 404

After having read a lot of posts on the topic of URL rewriting, I still remain stuck with `404` status errors.

**My goal:**

A **'static'** rewrite of URLs, as follows (user clicks or enters the one URL/script, but internally the other one is being executed - the parameters are also 'static', hence I think I cannot use any kind of pattern `(*.)` and `$1` in the rule...:

- `domain.tld/en/abc.php?foo` to `domain.tld/en/xyz.php?bar` (1st level)
- `domain.tld/en/abc.php?foo&blabla` to `domain.tld/en/xyz.php?bar&otherstring` (2nd level)

**Additional Info:**

- Directory 'en' exists.
- Script abc.php **does not** exist
- Script xyz.php exists and works fine with the given static parameter(s)

**My .htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/abc\.php\?foo&blabla$ /en/xyz.php?bar&otherstring [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^en/abc\.php\?foo$ /en/xyz.php?bar [NC,L]
```

I already get a `404` error on this simpler last rule. I don't have access to the rewritelog.

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions to other Stack Exchange sites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114786/htaccess-404-when-rewriting-abc-phpfoo-to-xyz-phpbar

Comment: Sorry. I only realised later that this webmasters' site may be better suited.

Comment: NBD, it is better suited here because it's not about programming and will likely get closed there anyway. That's just to let others know to check the answers there too (and a reminder for them). Welcome to the site by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check for the query string using the `RewriteRule` pattern (the query string is stripped before pattern matching, as is the hostname, etc). So, the rules you stated above simply won't match and you'll get a 404. However, you can use the `RewriteCond` directive to check the query string:

For example:

`domain.tld/en/abc.php?foo` to `domain.tld/en/xyz.php?bar`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =foo
RewriteRule ^en/abc\.php$ /en/xyz.php?bar [L]
```

Note that this matches the exact query string "foo". I've removed the `NC` flag, unless you specifically need a case-insensitive match?

Comment: OK,thx. So am I right when for 2 params, it would be:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_QUERY_STRING}=foo&blabla
Rewriterule ^en/abc\.php$ /en/xyz.php?bar&otherstring [L]

Comment: Yes, that looks OK. Note there is a space before the `=`. (The `=` operator makes an exact string match as opposed to a regular expression.)

Comment: I just tested your solution, but adding the RewriteCond to my .htaccess produced a 500 Internal Server Error. When removing the RewriteCond, the 500 error is gone. ??

Comment: Sorry, it should be `QUERY_STRING`, not `HTTP_QUERY_STRING` as in my original post, just updated it.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I put a space after the = and it gave me the 500. I removed the space and the error is gone :-)

Comment: Yeah, that `=` is a special operator that is prefixed (with no space) to the string you are matching. In this case `=foo` is the same as `^foo$` (with start/end position markers).

Comment: Yes !!!!! Everything works fine according to your solution!!! And you saved my day (and night) !